# vertical center Headline - Beetle HTML5 Template

Tags: javascript, css, html, center

I will use the [Beetle HTML5 Template](http://themes.mokaine.com/beetle-html/home-01.html).
Which looks good after download and view in the browser but when I switch to the chrome mobile view the headline is not centered in the view.

Original on http://themes.mokaine.com/beetle-html/home-01.html :

[image: original]

and here the downloaded Version:

[image]

here is the JS Part for center the headline:

```
pxImgCaption.each(function () {

                var $this = $(this);

                $this.css({
                    top: ((pxWrapper.height() + headerHeight / 2) - $this.outerHeight()) / 2
                });

            });
```

here the full JS file:
http://themes.mokaine.com/beetle-html/js/beetle.js

Comment: have you tried anything so far to center it?

Comment: No I didnt change anything in the code. That's what i dont understand.

Comment: just to make sure, you want the "beetle" in the top to be centered?

Comment: no, i want the Jules and Jim centered like in the original version.

Comment: The online version is centered. The downloaded dont work.

Comment: ah, ok. and the JS is the same in the downloaded and in the online version?

Comment: yes, it is all the same

Comment: any errors in the developer console?

Comment: only this
**Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: not all, not all, only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)**

but I dont think that´s for this error

Answer (score 0):

If you check beetle wordpress with Chrome Inspector, You will notice they are adding